# How to compile a Windows binary in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, qt, ubuntu

I have a Qt application that I can compile in Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit and on Windows. However, I would like to avoid switching to Windows every time I want to compile the Windows version.

Is there a way I can compile a Windows Qt executable in Ubuntu with mingw32 or something?

Further, is there a way to integrate that compiler into Qt Creator?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "cross-compiler". Here's a related thread on the Ubuntu forums, FWIW: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=22879

Comment: alternatively you could use a virtual machine. :)

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't explain how to integrate with Qt.

Comment: QtCreator can drive any makefile (or makefile-like) building procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~clazzes.org/+archive/ppa) (Personal Package Archive) for some people who are cross-compiling Qt and related software on Ubuntu for Windows. The PPA contains both the cross-compilers and the dependencies you will need to cross-compile Qt programs. If you look at the source packages there, I think you will be able to figure out how to configure your projects and build them.

Comment: Oh yeah. What a coincidence - I just joined LaunchPad a few days ago!

Answer (score 0):

If you most of your time spend coding with Qt on Linux (for example, Ubuntu), you may produce some experiment: install [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download), install [Qt SDK for Windows](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) with Wine and tried to build some simple project!

And if you don't like crazy things, which I wrote above, just use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).